# Codeigniter A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, google-chrome

we are facing 1064 database error in google chrome browser sometimes. but its working fine in other browsers. please let me know any solutions you have.

**Error Code:**

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 select * from
>   tbl_user_rights where usr_id=**

**Filename:** `helpers/common_helper.php`
Line Number: 42**

**program code:-**

```
function user_has_right($rights_id) {
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('user_model');
    $user_id = $CI->session->userdata('user_id');
    $query = $CI->db->query("select * from " . TBL_USERS_RIGHTS . " where usr_id=" . $user_id);
    $rights = $query->result();
    $user_right = array();
    foreach ($rights as $right) {
        array_push($user_right, $right->sm_id);
    }// print_r($user_right);exit;
    if (in_array($rights_id, $user_right)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: fire the select query only when  $user_id is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add condition for either user id exist or not. Try to put condition as in below code. Hope this can help you to solve this issue.

```
function user_has_right($rights_id) {
$CI = get_instance();
if($CI->session->userdata('user_id') != '')
{
    $CI->load->model('user_model');
    $user_id = $CI->session->userdata('user_id');
    $query = $CI->db->query("select * from " . TBL_USERS_RIGHTS . " where usr_id=" . $user_id);
    $rights = $query->result();
    $user_right = array();
    foreach ($rights as $right) {
        array_push($user_right, $right->sm_id);
    }// print_r($user_right);exit;
    if (in_array($rights_id, $user_right)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
 }
 else
 {
      return FALSE;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
$user_id = $CI->session->userdata('user_id');
$user_id = ($user_id && is_numeric($user_id)) ? $user_id : 0;
```

It will set user_id as zero if it not getting any thing

Answer (score 0):

The query is failing because the `user_id` is empty from the session. I would suggest returning false if the `user_id` is empty (by checking if it is null) and I even wrote a query builder get that has the benefits of escaping the `user_id`:

```
function user_has_right($rights_id) {
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->load->model('user_model'); // not sure where this is being used...
    $user_id = $CI->session->userdata('user_id');
    if (is_null($user_id)) {
        return false;
    }
    $query = $CI->db->get_where('tbl_users_rights', array('usr_id' => $user_id));
    //$query = $CI->db->query("select * from " . TBL_USERS_RIGHTS . " where usr_id=" . $user_id);
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) {
         return false;
    }
    $rights = $query->result();
    $user_right = array();
    foreach ($rights as $right) {
        array_push($user_right, $right->sm_id);
    }// print_r($user_right);exit;
    if (in_array($rights_id, $user_right)) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```